# Send email from googlesheet stops for loop with invalid email. How to skip

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-forms

I have a googlescript that sends emails. It is working well but it seems to completely stop when it hits an invalid email. There's one field that is a manually inputted email address that is periodically incorrect. I was out of office for a week and 60 emails failed because the script stopped at one row because of invalid email and didn't move forward. I don't write in javascript/googlescript so this has been a very challenging project for me. I appreciate any help.

I'll assume that I need to add something that skips a row if the email is invalid. What do I need to change in my script? Is there a way to push back to the submitter if he/she entered an invalid email address (the script is triggered via form submit)? I'm open to alternatives and recommendations if there are best practices.

**Example of error message**
'Exception: Invalid email: g.d@v.com, **n.t@v.com`**, c.b@v.com, z.l@v.com
at EmailHRBPonFormSubmit(Auto Emails on Submit:40:13)'

```js
function EmailTeamonFormSubmit() {
  
  var sheet= SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Form Responses 1");
  var startRow = 2;                            
  var numRows = sheet.getLastRow()-1;        // Number of rows to process
  var lastColumn = sheet.getLastColumn();      // Last column
  var dataRange = sheet.getRange(startRow, 1, numRows, lastColumn) // get the data range of the active sheet
  var data = dataRange.getValues();            // get values for each row in the range


  //////////////////////////////////////////////
 //create a for loop; define variables based on increasing count, starting from zero

for (var i = 0;  i < data.length; i++) {
  var row = data[i];
    var emailSubmitter = row[1];
    var submitter = row[5];
    var emailStakeholder = row[11];
    var stakeholder = row[10];
    var jobName = row[12];
    var emailSentStatus = row[49]
    var BusinessPartneremail = row[47]
    var BusninessPartnername = row[48]
    var subject =  'New Submission: '+jobName;
    var uniqueID = row[46]
    var Responses = row[45] //copy of the entire form response
    
    //message to the team
    var message = "Hello, "+
    BusninessPartnername+ ", " +stakeholder+ 
      ""+
    ", A new submission was sent by " +submitter+ ". The Unique ID is: " +uniqueID+ ". The responses are below." 
   
    +Responses;
    //send emails only if Status and email Status criteria are met
      
  if (emailSentStatus !== "Team email Sent"){
    MailApp.sendEmail(emailSubmitter+", "+emailStakeholder+", "+BusinessPartneremail, subject, message,{noReply: true});  //write email and send
    
      sheet.getRange(startRow + i, lastColumn).setValue("Team email Sent");// write email sent when done 
      SpreadsheetApp.flush(); //refresh spreadsheet
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A quick solution is to add a [try/catch](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/try...catch). Essentially, when `MailApp.sendEmail` fails, the script will continue from the next iteration and it won't stop until it reaches `data.length`.

Wrap the if statement that contains the `MailApp.sendEmail` function like this:

```
function EmailTeamonFormSubmit() {
  
  var sheet= SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Form Responses 1");
  var startRow = 2;                            
  var numRows = sheet.getLastRow()-1;        // Number of rows to process
  var lastColumn = sheet.getLastColumn();      // Last column
  var dataRange = sheet.getRange(startRow, 1, numRows, lastColumn) // get the data range of the active sheet
  var data = dataRange.getValues();            // get values for each row in the range


  //////////////////////////////////////////////
 //create a for loop; define variables based on increasing count, starting from zero

for (var i = 0;  i < data.length; i++) {
  var row = data[i];
    var emailSubmitter = row[1];
    var submitter = row[5];
    var emailStakeholder = row[11];
    var stakeholder = row[10];
    var jobName = row[12];
    var emailSentStatus = row[49]
    var BusinessPartneremail = row[47]
    var BusninessPartnername = row[48]
    var subject =  'New Submission: '+jobName;
    var uniqueID = row[46]
    var Responses = row[45] //copy of the entire form response
    
    //message to the team
    var message = "Hello, "+
    BusninessPartnername+ ", " +stakeholder+ 
      ""+
    ", A new submission was sent by " +submitter+ ". The Unique ID is: " +uniqueID+ ". The responses are below." 
   
    +Responses;
    //send emails only if Status and email Status criteria are met
      
  try{
  if (emailSentStatus !== "Team email Sent"){
    MailApp.sendEmail(emailSubmitter+", "+emailStakeholder+", "+BusinessPartneremail, subject, message,{noReply: true});  //write email and send
    
      sheet.getRange(startRow + i, lastColumn).setValue("Team email Sent");// write email sent when done 
      SpreadsheetApp.flush(); //refresh spreadsheet
    }
  } // try
  
  catch(e) {continue;}
  
}
}
```